# Cache in angular datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I'm using angular datatables (v0.5.1) on a project and I've detected a weird "cache" behaviour.

The data for the datatable is fetched from an API. There is a promise and when the data is received, the promise is resolved and the data is showed on the table.

But if I ask for a second set of data (different, with other date ranges or filters), when it's received, the data is drawed with the information it had the first time, not the new one.

Edit: Sorry - Adding some code :)

This is part of the controller that loads the data and sends it to the directive:

```js
function ChannelsController(...) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.showLoadingMetrics = true;

  activate();
  
  function activate() {
    setFilters();
    loadData(); 
  }

  // Query the API and load data into table
  function loadData() {
    vm.metricsData = MetricsService.getMetrics(filters);
    vm.metricsData.then(function(resolvedPromise) {
      readTableConfiguration(resolvedPromise);

      // remove spinner
      vm.showLoadingMetrics = false;
    });
  }

  // builds the Table configuration from the promise
  function readTableConfiguration(resolvedPromise) {
    vm.chartConfig.metrics = resolvedPromise.data.definitions.columns;
  }
  
}
```

I'm using a directive for the table:

```html
<tb-table-channels table-data="vm.metricsData" table-config="vm.chartConfig.metrics"></tb-table-channels>
```

Now, the first time it runs perfect, but there's a date filter on the same page and when the user selects a different date, the $state is changed and the date is sent as parameters, so I have the following code:

```js
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  vm.showLoadingMetrics = true;

  // read parameters
  setFilters();

  // reload data
  loadData();
});
```

The data from the API is in fact, different, but yet the table is drawn  with the data it had the first time.

Does anybody have any clues about what can be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. To get the best responses, can you share your code so we can take a look at it?

Comment: are you using $q.defer() for promises? and where is your resolving code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using $q.defer() for promises and I've just added some code to show how I used it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself, the problem wasn't related to any cache, the problem was the promise I used to fetch data from the API.

Since a promise can only be resolved once, only the first time it was resolved was working fine, every resolution after the first one would fail because it was already resolved and the data was the same.

Solution was to use a new promise on every load attempt.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Adding some code that fixed my issue:

```js
function getMetrics(filters) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    var params = {};

    if (filters.dateRange && filters.dateRange.start && filters.dateRange.end) {
      // set date filter
      params.start_date = moment(filters.dateRange.start).unix();
      params.end_date = moment(filters.dateRange.end).unix();
    } else {
      // set a default date filter
      params.start_date = moment().subtract(29, 'days').unix();
      params.end_date = moment().unix();
    }

    if (filters.groupBy && typeof filters.groupBy === 'string') {
      params.group_by = filters.groupBy;
    } else {
      params.group_by = DEFAULT_FILTERS.groupBy;
    }

    if (filters.channel && filters.channel.slug) {
      params.channel = filters.channel.slug;
    }

    if (filters.campaign && filters.campaign.id) {
      params.campaign = filters.campaign.id;
    }

    // call api service
    resolve(ApiService.getMetrics(params));
  });
}
```

So basically, each time I ask for data I'm using the MetricsService.getMetrics() (in the loadData() function) so I'm just returning a new promise (by calling the $q constructor into the getMetrics method and returning that promise).

The promise is resolved when the API returns the data. The ApiService is just another layer to handle API requests (authorization, paths, methods, etc).